# Given that an ocean did not touch the ground, how would the way waves function change?

Tags: science-fiction, earth-like, geography

## The Premise

- An earth-like world (gravity, 1 moon, distance from star)
- Oceans do not touch the ground (ignoring the how for this premise, but for consistency we'll say it's floating atop **1 km** of air)
- Oceans still in contact with shorelines (allowed to touch ground starting a maximum of 1km from shore)

#### What the question is *NOT*

- How ocean life would be affected
- What destruction would be caused to the atmosphere
- Feasibility of the premise

### The Question

Given that an ocean didn't touch the ground outside of a 1km continental shelf allowance, how would natural ocean phenomena such as waves change?

##### Clarifications

I haven't been able to get on since posting the question, so I'll give some clarifications here:

- The illustration below shows what I was trying to say: the water can only sit on top of land within 1 km of a continent, everywhere else has ~ 1 km of air between the water and ground 
  [image: MS Paint example]
- For the purposes of this premise, we can assume that the air being contained by the water bodies is air that is either more dense or less buoyant than the water atop it.
- We can assume there is very little, if any, air flow getting below the water bodies from above them.
- **I care less about the way the waves react upon reaching the shelf, and more about how they change (if they change at all) out on the open waters**

**Disclaimer**
If you notice anything wrong with my post, I'm still learning, and am always open to suggestions for improvement!

Comment: Are there winds / currents on the upper and lower atmospheric levels?
Is the composition of the upper and lower atmospheric levels the same? ie: density pressure etc.

Comment: when you say "it doesn't touch the ground", what is the distance between ground and water?

Comment: @Gillgamesh in every way apart from the oceans floating off the ground, the planet is the exact same as earth

Comment: @L.Dutch added a clarification

Comment: What do you mean by " doesn't touch the ground outside of a 1km continental shelf allowance"? Can you describe how it doesn't touch the ground. Waves in a fluid are highly dependent upon the surface conditions, without knowing what's interacting with the surface and how this question lacks sufficient details to be easily answerable.

Comment: Is the layer ocean a general uniform thickness? 
(I keep imagining an computer AI going insane trying to model this scenario :)

Comment: Really need more information as to how the layer of water is suspended above the lower atmospheric level. If there is any energy being imparted "upwards" to the bottom of the ocean above, after some wave action energy is transmitted downward  you can see this will contribute to wave formation as opposed to energy being reflected by a static ocean floor.

Comment: `ignoring the how for this premise` this is a hard premise to ignore as the physics of gravity which cause the waves would also effect the surface below.  If it was a force field it might react one way, if it was something less buoyant than your ocean it might act another.

Comment: Lets ignore the fact that we are talking about an ocean of water for a moment and instead talk about air which floats on top of water.  While we dont see it directly, air also has waves and tides that are affected by both the position of the moon and the heat of the sun. There is a visible ripple between water and air just like there would be a ripple between air and space ... though harder to define the exact boundary point.

Comment: The current description doesn't make any sense. The ocean is floating on 1km of air... but it touches the ground 1km from "shore"?? Wtf? You need a picture.

Comment: @sphennings the 1km shelf allowance is to say that I care more about how the waves on the open seas would react than the waves once they reach land. It also makes the water act as a "lid", so to speak, so there's no real airflow beneath the water to cause underwaves. Let's assume for this premise that the air beneath the water is less buoyant than the water, thus allowing the water to "float" on top of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It wouldn't change much

Your scenario is roughly equivalent to "There's a huge, 1 km deep, pocket of air at the bottom of the ocean, and all the ground below the continental shelf is dry"

Waves on the ocean are mostly governed by surface effects, so what is happening deep  below the surface will be largely unaffected. That isn't to say that if this change happened abruptly that there wouldn't be some big changes in the ocean, but after things settled down, the waves and the ocean would settle down and a new normal would be established.

Comment: With the possibility though, that now as well as waves on the upper surface of the oceans, there may also be waves (of some sort) on the *undersurface*. Of course, their nature would depend strongly on whatever McGuffin you are choosing to explain why the oceans float in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

### There would be (virtually) no tsunamis

Tsunamis are caused by the land displacing large amounts of water when an earthquake occurs. With a 1km air buffer between land and sea, there would not be a direct land-water interface to move the water, and the air would likely absorb most (if not all) of that energy.

Answer (score 3):

## Same amount of fluid

If the ocean is sitting atop a layer of air, then we still have the same volume of fluid. The "ceiling" of the air layer, where it meets the ocean, might fluctuate by a very small amount (centimeters at most) in some places.

"What about the density?"

The deep ocean has very little effect on waves, nor is it very affected by waves. So, assuming that your scenario is possible in your world, it wouldn't matter. The waves on the surface of the ocean would be essentially identical.

The real problem is with the air itself. In order for the ocean to sit on top of it, you will need some sort of magic holding it up, otherwise the air pressure of your underwater "atmosphere" is going to be just as high as it would be under the same depth of water--no one could live there. You will also need to explain how the air doesn't just bubble up through the ocean. Surface tension alone won't cut it.